Ruby (Windows) - Bundle install or update failing - fail to install openssl
Due to a new Heroku update (which keep the Gemfile.lock even if it's windows), I am trying to do a new bundle install (or bundle update, both are failing), because otherwise I can't push my code onto Heroku
Doing a "bundle install" when the Gemfile.lock exists work, but when i am trying to generate a new one, the error happen
But when trying to fetch the opsenssl gem, I have a 404 error
I don't know why this happen, I have made multiple bundle install (and some update) in the past and I have never encountered this error
Here is the full log I got (the text is in french, but basically it saying "error : failed to get file "mingw..." from repo.msys2.org"...)
Fetching https://github.com/thegengen/cloudprint.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies..............................................................................................................................................................................
Using rake 13.2.1 (was 13.0.1)
Using concurrent-ruby 1.3.3 (was 1.2.3)
Using i18n 1.14.5 (was 1.14.4)
Using minitest 5.24.1 (was 5.22.3)
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.11
Using activesupport 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using builder 3.3.0 (was 3.2.4)
Using erubi 1.13.0 (was 1.9.0)
Using racc 1.8.0
Using nokogiri 1.13.10 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.10.9)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.2.0 (was 2.0.3)
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.22.0 (was 2.4.0)
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.5.0 (was 1.3.0)
Using actionview 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using rack 2.2.9 (was 2.2.2)
Using rack-test 2.1.0 (was 1.1.0)
Using actionpack 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using nio4r 2.7.3 (was 2.5.2)
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5 (was 0.1.4)
Using websocket-driver 0.7.6 (was 0.7.1)
Using actioncable 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using globalid 1.1.0 (was 0.4.2)
Using activejob 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using mini_mime 1.1.5 (was 1.0.2)
Using date 3.3.4
Using timeout 0.4.1
Using net-protocol 0.2.2
Using net-imap 0.3.7
Using net-pop 0.1.2
Using net-smtp 0.5.0
Using mail 2.8.1 (was 2.7.1)
Using actionmailer 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using activemodel 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using activemodel-serializers-xml 1.0.2
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using activeresource 5.1.1 (was 5.1.0)
Using marcel 1.0.4 (was 0.3.3)
Using activestorage 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using public_suffix 5.1.1 (was 4.0.3)
Using addressable 2.8.7 (was 2.7.0)
Using ast 2.4.2 (was 2.4.0)
Using execjs 2.9.1 (was 2.7.0)
Using autoprefixer-rails 10.4.16.0 (was 9.7.5)
Using babel-source 5.8.35
Using babel-transpiler 0.7.0
Using backport 1.2.0 (was 1.1.2)
Using base64 0.2.0
Using benchmark 0.3.0 (was 0.1.0)
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using popper_js 2.11.8 (was 1.16.0)
Using bootstrap 5.3.3 (was 4.4.1)
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using byebug 11.1.3 (was 11.1.1)
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using childprocess 4.1.0 (was 3.0.0)
Using json 1.8.6
Using multipart-post 2.4.1 (was 2.1.1)
Using faraday 0.15.4
Using jwt 2.8.2 (was 2.2.1)
Using multi_json 1.15.0 (was 1.14.1)
Using multi_xml 0.6.0
Using oauth2 1.4.4
Using cloudprint 0.3.3 from https://github.com/thegengen/cloudprint.git (at master@f5ee5d1)
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 1.1.0 (was 1.0.0)
Using thor 1.3.1 (was 1.0.1)
Using railties 5.2.8.1 (was 5.2.4.2)
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using matrix 0.4.2
Using ruby-rc4 0.1.5
Using combine_pdf 1.0.26 (was 1.0.16)
Using connection_pool 2.4.1 (was 2.2.2)
Using declarative 0.0.20 (was 0.0.10)
Using diff-lcs 1.5.1 (was 1.4.4)
Using digest-crc 0.6.5 (was 0.5.1)
Using dotenv 2.8.1 (was 2.7.5)
Using e2mmap 0.1.0
Using faraday_middleware 0.14.0
Using httparty 0.13.7
Using fedex 3.10.1
Using ffi 1.16.3 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.12.2)
Using google-protobuf 3.23.4 (x64-mingw32) (was 3.11.4)
Using googleapis-common-protos-types 1.12.0 (was 1.0.4)
Using grpc 1.58.0 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.28.0)
Using googleapis-common-protos 1.4.0 (was 1.3.9)
Using memoist 0.16.2
Using os 1.1.4 (was 1.1.0)
Using signet 0.12.0
Using googleauth 0.10.0
Using gapic-common 0.3.4
Using get_process_mem 0.2.7 (was 0.2.5)
Using gibbon 3.2.0
Using httpclient 2.8.3
Using trailblazer-option 0.1.2
Using uber 0.1.0
Using representable 3.2.0 (was 3.0.4)
Using retriable 3.1.2
Using google-api-client 0.37.2
Using rly 0.2.3
Using google-gax 1.8.2 (was 1.8.1)
Using grpc-google-iam-v1 0.6.11 (was 0.6.9)
Using google-cloud-asset 0.8.1
Using google-cloud-env 1.3.0
Using google-cloud-errors 1.3.1 (was 1.0.0)
Using google-cloud-core 1.6.1 (was 1.5.0)
Using google-cloud-bigquery 1.23.0 (was 1.21.0)
Using google-cloud-bigquery-data_transfer 0.9.0 (was 0.8.0)
Using google-cloud-bigtable 1.3.0 (was 1.2.0)
Using google-cloud-container 0.11.0 (was 0.10.1)
Using google-cloud-dataproc 0.10.0
Using google-cloud-datastore 1.8.2 (was 1.8.0)
Using google-cloud-dialogflow 0.15.0
Using google-cloud-dlp 0.15.0
Using zonefile 1.06
Using google-cloud-dns 0.33.0 (was 0.32.0)
Using google-cloud-error_reporting-v1beta1 0.4.0
Using stackdriver-core 1.5.0 (was 1.4.0)
Using google-cloud-error_reporting 0.42.3 (was 0.35.0)
Using rbtree 0.4.6 (was 0.4.2)
Using google-cloud-firestore 1.4.4 (was 1.4.0)
Using google-cloud-kms 1.6.0 (was 1.5.1)
Using google-cloud-language 0.36.0
Using google-cloud-logging 1.10.9 (was 1.10.2)
Using google-cloud-monitoring 0.38.0 (was 0.37.1)
Using google-cloud-os_login 0.7.0 (was 0.6.1)
Using google-cloud-phishing_protection-v1beta1 0.3.0
Using google-cloud-phishing_protection 0.12.0 (was 0.4.1)
Using google-cloud-pubsub 1.10.0 (was 1.5.0)
Using google-cloud-recaptcha_enterprise 0.6.0 (was 0.5.1)
Using google-cloud-redis 0.8.2
Using google-cloud-resource_manager 0.34.0 (was 0.33.2)
Using google-cloud-scheduler 1.3.1
Using google-cloud-security_center 0.10.0
Using google-cloud-spanner 1.16.2 (was 1.16.0)
Using google-cloud-speech 0.41.0
Using google-cloud-storage 1.29.2 (was 1.25.1)
Using google-cloud-talent-v4beta1 0.4.0
Using google-cloud-talent 0.20.0 (was 0.10.0)
Using google-cloud-tasks 1.5.1
Using google-cloud-text_to_speech 0.7.0 (was 0.6.1)
Using google-cloud-trace-v1 0.3.0
Using google-cloud-trace-v2 0.3.0
Using google-cloud-trace 0.42.2 (was 0.38.0)
Using google-cloud-translate 2.1.1
Using google-cloud-video_intelligence 2.1.1
Using google-cloud-vision 0.38.0
Using google-cloud 0.64.0
Using graphql 1.10.3
Using graphql-client 0.18.0
Using hashie 5.0.0 (was 4.1.0)
Using holidays 8.8.0 (was 8.1.0)
Using mini_magick 4.13.1 (was 4.10.1)
Using img2zpl 1.0.1
Using jaro_winkler 1.6.0 (was 1.5.4)
Using jquery-rails 4.6.0 (was 4.3.5)
Using jsonl 0.1.5
Using strscan 3.1.0
Using rexml 3.3.1 (was 3.2.4)
Using kramdown 2.4.0
Using kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Using labelary 0.2.0
Using request_store 1.7.0 (was 1.5.0)
Using lograge 0.14.0 (was 0.11.2)
Using lograge-sql 2.3.2 (was 1.1.0)
Using omniauth 1.9.1
Using omniauth-oauth2 1.7.3 (was 1.6.0)
Using omniauth-google-oauth2 0.8.0
Fetching openssl 3.1.0 (was 2.1.2)
Installing openssl 3.1.0 (was 2.1.2) with native extensions
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.13-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.13-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.13-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1-4.13-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis mirror.yandex.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
avertissement : erreur lors de la récupération de certains fichiers
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.23.15-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.23.15-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.23.15-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit-0.23.15-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis mirror.yandex.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
avertissement : erreur lors de la récupération de certains fichiers
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20180409-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20180409-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20180409-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates-20180409-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis mirror.yandex.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
avertissement : erreur lors de la récupération de certains fichiers
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.b-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.b-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.b-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
erreur : échec de récupération du fichier « mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl-1.1.1.b-1-any.pkg.tar.xz » depuis mirror.yandex.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
avertissement : erreur lors de la récupération de certains fichiers
erreur : la validation de la transaction a échoué (erreur non prévue)
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/openssl-3.1.0/ext/openssl
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20240702-17764-1aanbdt.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_io_maybe_wait(0, Qnil, Qnil, Qnil) in ruby/io.h... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for -lws2_32... yes
checking for whether -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 is accepted as CFLAGS... yes
checking for whether -fstack-protector is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
checking for -lssp... yes
checking for -lgdi32... yes
checking for -lcrypt32... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-dir
        --without-openssl-dir
        --with-openssl-include
        --without-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
        --with-openssl-lib
        --without-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib
        --with-kerberos-dir
        --without-kerberos-dir
        --with-kerberos-include
        --without-kerberos-include=${kerberos-dir}/include
        --with-kerberos-lib
        --without-kerberos-lib=${kerberos-dir}/lib
        --with-debug
        --without-debug
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-ws2_32lib
        --without-ws2_32lib
        --with-ssplib
        --without-ssplib
        --with-openssl-config
        --without-openssl-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-gdi32lib
        --without-gdi32lib
        --with-crypt32lib
        --without-crypt32lib
extconf.rb:101:in `<main>': OpenSSL library could not be found. You might want
to use --with-openssl-dir=<dir> option to specify the prefix where OpenSSL is
installed. (RuntimeError)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/openssl-3.1.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/openssl-3.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/openssl-3.1.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing openssl (3.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install openssl -v '3.1.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  openssl

OS : Windows 10
Ruby version : "ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]"
Bundler version : "Bundler version 2.1.4"
Rails version (don't know if useful): "Rails 5.2.4.2"
(I know I have some gem update to do, but I had no problem to push last week)
Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue ?
Thanks
What i Tried : Bundle install / bundle update (platform : Windows)
What i Expected : The bundle work
What happened : Error 404 when fetching openssl
